# Replace variables in webpack bundle without breaking the source map and without a rebuild

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have some variables in my javascript code (which is bundled with webpack) that need to be replaced per-environment:

```
const AUTHENTICATE_URL = '{{conf.authenticate_url}}'
```

How do I do this without re-running the build for each environment (running the build is too slow). I cannot have a second  tag in my html, I need to have only one  tag that contains the bundle.

Currently I just replace those variables using a template processor but this breaks the source mapping and means that I can potentially replace stuff I didn't mean to replace.

Comment: You need some way to tell your environments apart though if you aren't going to re-build, give me an example of how in regular JS you would tell the difference.

Comment: Quite strange request. Usually per-environment stuff is supposed to be defined on the building phase. Did you try to update your Node? Recent versions should run a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

It's really not the best idea to only build everything one time and stick the same code in every environment, but if that is the way it has to be...

[Webpack Define plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)

webpack

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'SERVICE_URL_DEV': JSON.stringify('http://dev.example.com'),
  'SERVICE_URL': JSON.stringify('http://example.com')
});
```

JS

```
if (DEV_ENVIRONMENT) {
  console.log(SERVICE_URL_DEV);
} else {
  console.log(SERVICE_URL);
}
```

I'm assuming here that you can tell the difference which environment you are in somehow and I'm speculating you had a constant in your code you figured out via the URL or something from the window, and it was called DEV_ENVIRONMENT which was true in dev and false in prod.

Edit: Since we don't really know what you mean 100%. In the event you never want to rebuild and just need to change a variable per environment whenever.

Using axios.

variable.json file on each environment, different URLs in each

```
{authUrl: 'https://dev.example.com'}
```

JS File in app

```
let AUTHENTICATE_URL;
axios.get('https://yoururl.com/path/to/variable.json').then((response) => {
  AUTHENTICATE_URL = response.data.authUrl;
});
```

Comment: This still requires rebuilding to get any changes applied which the OP don't want

Comment: No it doesn't if he needs a variable to change per environment, you must know what it is in each one. So you define the possibilities, globalize it, then run an if to switch inbetween.

Comment: Also this replacement of the variables, because it's coming from webpack would be fine in any source-map as well

Comment: He wants to change a variable's value _**without**_ rebuilding at all, i.e. without running webpack. How could your plugin help with it?

Comment: You are going to need to run webpack one time correct? Or else you have no JS, so we are going to assume running webpack one time initially is obvious. So if you have 2 environments running the same code and you need the auth_url to be different in each one. You use webpack define to define your dev auth_url and your prod auth_url. You build it ONE time and both those value exist. Then you have to odviously have some way of knowing where you are. So you switch AUTHENTICATE_URL back and forth between your webpack defined URLS in each environment.

Comment: It seems that you got the OP wrong. AFAIU he don't want to make variable's value different in different environments, he wants to _**change**_ its value in all environments at once _**without rebuilding**_

Comment: Quote "How do I do this without re-running the build for each environment (running the build is too slow). I cannot have a second tag in my html, I need to have only one tag that contains the bundle.". So what this says to me quite clearly is that running the build one time is acceptable, odviously he needs to change his code once in awhile... the issue is running the build 2,3,4 times in a row one per environment.

Comment: Our discussion doesn't make sense. Let the OP clarify what he really needs.

Comment: There we go, I think that should cover each scenario

Comment: This requires rebuilding for each environment. So does not answer my question.

Comment: @gtz are we talking about the same thing because both of these solutions would only require you to build the JS one time and would work in multiple environments with a way to swap out a variable in either option. Maybe I'm not understand what your needing here. Maybe try expanding your example to include some more specifics.